# GLSL Error: 2001 - What does this error code mean?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I got this after querying the info logs when a compile error occurred. I have not been able to find a single resource that tells me what the error code even means!

Using Ubuntu 9.10 with an Intel mobile chipset that supports glsl 1.1. Mesa driver.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 110
in vec3 m2d_blendcolor;

out vec3 color;
// out vec2 texcoord0;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    color = m2d_blendcolor;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 110

in vec3 color;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

When I initialize my shader object, I call:

```
shader.bindAttrib(0, "m2d_vertex");
shader.bindAttrib(1, "m2d_texcoord0");
shader.bindAttrib(2, "m2d_blend_color");
```

these call

```
glBindAttribLocation(m_programID/*internal GLuint*/, index, attribName.c_str());
```

Is it that I'm binding the vertex attributes too soon? Do they have to be bound when the shader is bound?

Comment: What line generates the error code?

Comment: I dunno lol. MESA WON'T TELL ME! All it says in the log is "Error: 2001". Period.

Comment: Wait... your shader doesn't have m2d_texcoord0 and m2d_vertex... or even m2d_blend_color for that matter (check the underscore). I'd try fixing those first. Finally... that shader code doesn't look like GLSL to me...

Comment: m2d_* are vertex attributes I pass in from my compiled code.

Comment: Both shaders aren't valid GLSL 1.1. in/out can only be used for function parameters. It may be valid for GLSL 1.3 though. You also need to define the vertex attributes in the shader, it's not enough to just bind them in your program.

Comment: Are you for real!? Augh, I'll have to look up some old documentation then. Shouldn't be too hard. Or use cg instead.

Comment: Ok, so apparently "in" should be "attribute", uniform stays the same, and "out" should be "varying". I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: I was also leaving it up to the programmer to use the attributes if they want to. That's why they're commented out there.

Comment: "Open the pod bay doors, HAL."
Sorry for irrelevant comment, but I had to.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. With glsl 1.1, the in and out qualifiers are not valid.

See [Khronos OpenGL wiki - Type Qualifier (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)):

> The following qualifiers are deprecated as of GLSL 1.30 (OpenGL 3.0) and removed from GLSL 1.40 and above.
>
> The `attribute` qualifier is effectively equivalent to an input qualifier in vertex shaders. It cannot be used in any other shader stage. It cannot be used in interface blocks.
>
> The `varying` qualifier is equivalent to the input of a fragment shader or the output of a vertex shader. It cannot be used in any other shader stages. It cannot be used in interface blocks.